# $mul nested document field where might not exist

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-update

I have the following document:

```json
{
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "foo",
            "score" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to multiply the `score` field by `10`, only where it exists.

Using just dot notation:

```json
{
    $mul: {
        'results.score': NumberInt(10)
    }
}
```

Returns an error:

```
Cannot create field 'score' in element {results: [ { name: "foo", score: 10 }, { name: "bar" } ]}
```

I've tried using the new array filters:

```json
{
    $mul: {
        'results.$[result].score': NumberInt(10)
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        'result.grade': {
            $exists: true
        }
    }]
}
```

This gives me an error too:

```
No array filter found for identifier 'result' in path 'results.$[result].score'
```

I know that I could set a score field in all the documents and set it to zero, that wouldn't be a solution though as the lack of a score means that there isn't a score yet, rather that there is a score and it's `0`.

1. Can this be done?
2. Could this be done prior to version 3.6?

Comment: 2 issues I found, your `arrayFilters` option is referencing the wrong field and it looks like you are running your query in Robomongo which won't work. Try mongo shell instead and the correct query should be `db.collection.update(
  { "results.score": { "$exists": true } },
  { "$mul": { "results.$[result].score": 10 } },
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "result.score": { "$exists": true } }], "multi": true }
)`

Comment: @chridam  That's it.  Thank you.  I dread to think ho wlong it would have taken me to figure out that it didn't work in RoboMongo.