# Updating a nested array object in Mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is the json object

```
{
"account_id":"1",
"sections":[ {
    "section_name":"abc",
    "labels": [{
        "name": "label1",
        "value": "value1"
        },
        {
        "name": "label2",
        "value": "value2"
        }]
    },
     {
    "section_name":"def",
    "labels": [{
        "name": "label3",
        "value": "value3"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In this json object I wanted to change the value of label3 from value3 to value4 in the section def. There are different accounts but I have listed only one json object here.

I have used the below code, but it didn't work for me. Here I have passed section name(section), label name (label) and label value (value).

```
let query = {
account_id: event.accountId.toString(),
sections: {
    section_name: section,
    labels: {
    label_name: label
       }
     }
   };

   return using(connectDatabase(), db => {
   return db.collection(TABLE_NAME).updateOne(query, { $set: { 
  'sections.$.labels.$.value': value } });
  }).then(
    result => {
      cb(null, responseObj(result, 200));
    },
    err => {
      cb(responseObj(err, 500));
    }
  );
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: any errors while running that query?

Comment: Its not updating in the database.

Comment: posted answer using arrayFilters, hope it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using arrayFilters for nested objects

- Get main Object using account_id
- Using ArrayFiter `$[identfier].section : "def"` and `$[identfier].name: "label3"`

---

```
 db.collection(TABLE_NAME).updateOne({
    account_id: event.accountId.toString(),
    {
      "$set": {
        "sections.$[elem].labels.$[label].value": value
      }
    },
    {
      "arrayFilters": [{
        "elem.section_name": section
      }, {
      "label.name": label
      }]
    }
})
```

Please refer this link for more details - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Another example of arrayFilters with example - [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Comment: "Unsupported projection option: $set: { sections.$[elem].labels.$[label].value: \"valllll\" }",    <----- got this error

Comment: I have checked this in RoboMongo . Will that affect for this error?

Comment: @UthpalaPitawela, should enclose this quotes -  sections.$[elem].labels.$[label].value

Comment: I think the probelm is the MOngo version where this works only for versions higher 3.6 while my mongo version is  less than 3.6

Comment: oh k @UthpalaPitawela :) , Did you try to upgrade to 3.6 or are you trying for solution for version less than 3.6?

Comment: I think arrayFilter is not backward compatible , refer this link which seems to be open issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322834/robomongo-cant-use-array-filters

Comment: any luck @UthpalaPitawela

Comment: Imhoping  to upgrade   to anew Mongo   version, till  then   I have  changed   the  json  structure and followed   a different   approach;Thanks   for your answer

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Query**
You can use this query

```
db.testcol.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "sections.$[element].labels.$[element1].value" : "value1New" } },
   { multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.section_name": { $eq: "abc" } },  { "element1.name": { $eq: "label1" } }]
   }
)
```

You can check the following query: Where 1 is the index value of the array.

```
db.testcol.update(
    {
        account_id:"1", 
        "sections.section_name":"def"
    }, 
    {
        $set:{
            "sections.1.labels.1.value":"value8"
        }
    }
)
```

If you want to update all the values then you can use:

```
db.testcol.update(
{
    account_id:"1", 
    "sections.section_name":"def"
}, 
{
    $set:{
        "sections.$[].labels.$[].value":"value8"
    }
}
```

)

Please check and let me know if it is help-full.

Comment: This does not work as    sections.1.labels.1.value":"value8 , updates index 1 and sometimes the intended label not always in the index 0.